# Updating TabControl.DisplayRectangle manually

Tags: c#, .net, gdi+, tabcontrol, rectangles

I am writing a custom drawn `TabControl` class in C#.

My `InitializeComponent` method (which is called by the constructor) behaves like so, in order to custom draw the control:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
    this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
    this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
    this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
    this.UpdateStyles();
    this.DrawMode = TabDrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
}
```

The TabControl uses two rectangle surfaces;

- The `ClientRectangle` which contains the entire control
- The `DisplayRectangle` which is the portion of the control to display `TabPage` content

As I want to adjust the `DisplayRectangle`, I have overridden its property (which is get only):

```
public override Rectangle DisplayRectangle
{
    get
    {
        return this.displayRectangle; // points to a local rectangle, rather than base.DisplayRectangle
    }
}
```

Then I've overridden `OnSizeChanged` in order to update the display rectangle size:

```
protected override void OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnSizeChanged(e);
    this.displayRectangle = this.ClientRectangle;
    this.displayRectangle.Y += this.ItemSize.Height + 4;
    this.displayRectangle.Height -= this.ItemSize.Height + 4;
}
```

The problem I'm encountering is, when the `TabControl` is re-sized, the `DisplayRectangle` works and re-sizes accordingly, but when the parent form is maximized/minimized (thus changing the control size), the display rectangle does not update.

How should I go about fixing this? Are there any guidelines for managing the display rectangle manually?

Comment: If the TabControl's Dock property is set to "Fill" and you change the size of the form, the TabControl's size would change and the SizeChange event would be called (and thus your code would be executed). You can resize the TabControl "manually" by relying on the Main form resizing event if you wish. But I can only come up with a reason why the SizeChanged event of the TabControl is not called: its size hasn't changed.

Comment: Hard to see what you are trying to do, owner-draw is only for the tabs, not the pages.  Explain the *real* problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @HansPassant, I've fixed it. The problem was that I was not updating the bounds for each TabPage when the display rectangle changes. As soon as I updated the bounds for each TabPage, the display rectangle corrects itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered a couple of things which help to fix this issue. They are; to resize the display rectangle using an override of the OnResize method, and to set the bounds for each tab in the tab control when you have finished resizing the display rectangle...e.g:

```
protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnResize(e);
    this.displayRectangle = this.ClientRectangle;
    this.displayRectangle.Y += this.ItemSize.Height + 4;
    this.displayRectangle.Height -= this.ItemSize.Height + 4;
    foreach(TabPage page in this.TabPages)
    {
        page.SetBounds(
            this.DisplayRectangle.X, 
            this.DisplayRectangle.Y, 
            this.DisplayRectangle.Width, 
            this.DisplayRectangle.Height, 
            SpecifiedBounds.All
        );
    }
    this.Refresh();  // Can optimize this!
}
```